# customise spring boot actuator health status

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I access the /health endpoint from my Spring Boot application  it is returning a status of UP:

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```

But I want to customize my status like this:

```
{
  "status": "success"
}
```

How can I customize the status?

Answer (score 16):

Create a new health builder status and return it.

[Status](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Status.java)

```
@JsonProperty("status")
public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
}
```

**if implementing HealthIndicator**

```
@Component
public class HealthChecker implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        // Do checks ..
        // if no issues
        return Health.status("success").build();
    }   
}
```

**if extending AbstractHealthIndicator**

```
@Component
public class HealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Builder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.status("success").build();
    }
}
```

**Severity Order**

to make this work, you have to update the order of status severity by replacing `UP` with `success` or moving it before `UP`

*application.properties*

```
management.health.status.order=DOWN, OUT_OF_SERVICE, UNKNOWN, success
```

or

```
management.health.status.order=DOWN, OUT_OF_SERVICE, UNKNOWN, success, UP
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I got the output

Comment: @SupriyaCS, glad you got it sorted.  Do not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Hi @Sully , I'm looking for a way to mock the health status for testing, where I have a customized HealthIndicator service that use the actuator ping endpoint (if it's UP the service return "OK" , if its down the service return "Not_Ok" ) is there a way to mock the actuator pingHealthIndicator response? where I can force it to be down even if it is UP .

Comment: @BSL, you can override `management.health.status.order` with only `not_ok,ok`

Comment: Hello @Sully , Thank you so much for reply,  in my case I'm not creating a new status , I musing the same status(UP,DOWN) with a customised detail messages. In the service that Implement the HealthIndicator Interface , I'm retrieving the HealthIndicator beans (@Autowire HealthContributors[] healthContributor;)   and based on the state of each bean I'm building a specific  notification logic. In the UnitTest I have to mock the actuator endpoints (health bean) to test my service logic . please review this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879699/how-to-mock-actuator-health-in-unittest