# How to Mock /actuator/health in UnitTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-actuator

I'm intercepting the actuator/health endpoints in a custom Service by Auto-wiring the HealthContributor interface:

```
@Service
public class HealthCheckServiceImpl implements HealthIndicator{

  @Autowired HealthContributor[] healthContributors;

  @Override
  public Health health() {

    Map<String, String> components = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (HealthContributor healthContributor : healthContributors) {
      String componentName =
          healthContributor
              .getClass()
              .getSimpleName()
              .replace("HealthIndicator", "")
              .replace("HealthCheckIndicator", "");
      String status = ((HealthIndicator) (healthContributor)).health().getStatus().toString();
      components.put(componentName, status);
    }
    String healthComponentAsString = components.keySet().stream()
              .map(key -> key + "->" + components.get(key))
              .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    Boolean isComponentDown = components.containsValue("DOWN");
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isComponentDown)) {
      return Health.down().withDetail("Status: One of the API component is down. ","").build();
    } else {
      return Health.up().withDetail("Status: All API components are Up. ", "").build();
    }
  }
```

My question is, How can I mock the status of the components in order to test the health() method behavior.
I have tried

```
@MockBean
@Qualifier("pingHealthContributor") // intercepting just one component instead of 
                                    // HealthContributor[]
HealthContributor healthContributors;
```

but when I try to use Mockito. when() as follows:

```
String status="UP";
 when(((HealthIndicator) (healthContributors)).health().getStatus().toString()).thenReturn(status);
```

I get the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor$MockitoMock$297980690 cannot be cast to class org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator (org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor$MockitoMock$297980690 and org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

**Dependencies**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I have also tried to cast (PingHealthIndicator) (healthContributors) , without success since the healthConributors is a mock object and the PingHealthIndicator is a real object

Comment: what I have noticed is : 
1- if I do : `@MockBean PingHealthIndicator pingHealthIndicator; `
the `pingHealthIndicator.health()` method return null
2- if I autowire `@Autowired PingHealthIndicator pingHealthIndicator; `
the `pingHealthIndicator.health()` method return the correct status and details .